# Have Texas voters ever selected a Democrat for President?

Tags: united-states, presidential-election, voting, history, texas

This last American election gave me the impression that Texas voters were awfully close to electing a liberal, which is something to me that would be incredible.

[Apparently Biden got 46% of the vote which seems a stellar performance in Texas.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2020_United_States_presidential_election_in_Texas)

So my question is, have Texas voters ever selected a Democrat for president and, if not, how close was this last election to being the first time?

Comment: I think this may be an interesting question, given that the roles of the political parties have changed over the years.

Comment: @CortAmmon the problem is that the answer is so easily discovered with a little googling.

Comment: Most famously of all - the Texan - Lyndon Johnson!

Comment: Most states are pretty close to 50/50, it's more common than not for neither candidate to get over 60% of the vote in any particular state. The whole blue state/red state thing is kinda blown out of proportion.

Comment: It should be borne in mind that, from a historical perspective, the descriptive terms you used in your question — "a liberal" and "a Democrat" — are far from equivalent or interchangeable, particularly in Texas and other Southern states.

Comment: This isn't all that surprising, given that many people seem to move to Texas from California.

Comment: What did you find when you googled this?

Comment: https://xkcd.com/1122/ just because it fits this question so well...

Comment: @Dschoni maybe you haven't seen the updated one for 2020 https://xkcd.com/2383/

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Yes, in fact from Wikipedia's article on ["United States presidential elections in Texas"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_presidential_elections_in_Texas), we can see that Texas has elected a Democrat for president twenty-two times since 1876, most recently electing Jimmy Carter in the [1976 election](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1976_United_States_presidential_election_in_Texas). Republican candidates have only been elected fifteen times.

The highest percentage vote that a Democratic candidate received was in 1932, when FDR achieved 88.06% of the state's vote compared to Herbert Hoover's 11.35%.

Bear in mind that part of the reason for this historical inconsistency, despite the modern Republican party's relatively strong standing in Texas, is that the Republican and Democratic parties have 'switched sides' ideologically throughout their history - see [this related question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/54416/how-many-times-have-the-two-us-parties-switched-sides) - and the Democratic Party of a century ago is not particularly comparable to the Democratic Party of today.

Comment: The evidence to substantiate the Southern Strategy and the party switch of the 20th century is surprisingly lacking considering the number of times that it is stated. It is true the the interests and ideologies of each party has changed and realigned over the centuries, but the party switch as usually stated simply didn't occur. Very few ideological Democrats of the early 20th century became Republicans. It's more true that instead the population generally adopted principles which aligned with the Republican platform as society and culture changed.

Comment: @eques the Southern Strategy doesn't relate to the politicians. You are correct that very few actual politicians "switched sides", rather it's about techniques designed to switch the white southern "working class" voting base away from the Democratic party by use of veiled racism. With regards to that definition, the evidence is practically unassailable. So much so, that in 2005 the RNC chair and elements of the Bush campaign both apologized for their party's historic role in "exploiting racial tension" in a bid to reattract Black voters.

Comment: "Switched sides" is erroneous and misleading. It posits an polarization which did not exist.

Comment: @eques "The evidence to substantiate the Southern Strategy and the party switch of the 20th century is surprisingly lacking" There is a wide variety of positions for which the parties have switched sides. I don't see how that can be disputed. "It's more true that instead the population generally adopted principles which aligned with the Republican platform as society and culture changed" What does this mean? Do you mean that there was a constant Republican platform that Southerners generally adopted?

Comment: We shouldn't get distracted by debating the great party switch.  The answer here says that they switched sides "throughout their history" and links to a question about how many times they switched.  It's clear that they've changed positions on various issues at various times, so that you can't treat them as constant over the years, and that's all that this answer is claiming.  So there's no need to argue about anything more.

Comment: @Acccumulation Not so much a "consistent platform" as if the GOP had identical positions from 1930-1970, but that the demographics of the south shifted (e.g. significant migrations occurred from the Midwest to TX in the 50s), the acceptance of racism in the south declined (which is admitted even by many who repeat the Southern Strategy line), the cities especially in the peripheral south developed more industry and business and so on. When "switch sides" is used, it's predominately used to suggest segregationism switched from Democrat to GOP and rarely is it mentioned for any other position.

Comment: @TobyBartels the accepted answer to the linked question is actually about political realignments which is conceptually different from switching sides. Switching sides suggests a dichotomy or polarization which didn't quite exist for much of US history; there were two parties but it's not as though all issues were neatly divided into two ideological buckets each with one party to support and occasionally issues jumped buckets.The parties used to be more coalition-based and required balancing different concerns. So, yes I think critiquing the use of "switch sides" in this answer is valid.

Comment: @eques That's my point. You're equating "The Southern Strategy" with the idea that the parties "switched" (to be clear you're in no way alone in defining it that way). My point is that they didn't. A very specific voting demographic within a small subset of the country "switched". And they did so, not because entire platforms changed but because one party took an aggressively anti-segregation federal stance and the other took advantage of the dissonance between politician and base to 'capture' that demographic by use of closeted racism hinging on being anti-federalist-pro-freedom-to-segregate

Comment: @ShmuelNewmark but that's my point. To speak of a switch sides in any meaningful way (beyond a small number of individuals migrating one way or the other) suggests a polarization which didn't exist. And the rest of your comment highlights further: the idea that the other side "took advantage" with "closeted racism" is not actually supported by the historical record. It's at best supported by an equating of South with racism and a first-order interpretation of rough statistics.

Answer (score 19):

Yes, Texas has gone to the Democratic party several times. It is important to remember that the US Democratic Party is one of the oldest continuously operating political parties in the world (and the oldest in the US). In fact, over its history, Texas has generally *favored* the Democratic party from its statehood until the start of the [sixth party system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sixth_Party_System) some time in the 1960's or -70's. Two of these occasions (1968 and 1976) may have occurred under the current sixth party system, though there is debate about when exactly the new system began, and it is clear that for most of the sixth system, Texas has favored the Republican Party. These are the years in which Texas voted for a Democratic candidate for president (Presidential winners in **bold**):

- 1976 (**Dem. Jimmy Carter** vs. Rep. Gerald Ford)
- 1968 (Dem. Hubert Humphrey vs. **Rep. Richard Nixon** and Independent George Wallace)
- 1964 (**Dem. Lyndon Johnson** vs. Rep. Barry Goldwater)
- 1960 (**Dem. John F. Kennedy** vs. Rep. Richard Nixon)
- 1948 (**Dem. Harry Truman** vs. Rep. Thomas Dewey and Dixiecrat Strom Thurmond)
- 1944 (**Dem. Franklin D. Roosevelt** vs. Rep. Thomas Dewey)
- 1940 (**Dem. Franklin D. Roosevelt** vs. Rep. Wendell Willkie)
- 1936 (**Dem. Franklin D. Roosevelt** vs. Rep. Alf Landon)
- 1932 (**Dem. Franklin D. Roosevelt** vs. Rep. Herbert Hoover)
- 1924 (Dem. John Davis vs. **Rep. Calvin Coolidge** and Progessive Robert LaFollette)
- 1920 (Dem. James Cox vs. **Rep. Warren Harding**)
- 1916 (**Dem. Woodrow Wilson** vs. Rep. Charles Hughes)
- 1912 (**Dem. Woodrow Wilson** vs. Rep. William H. Taft and Progressive Theodore Roosevelt)
- 1908 (Dem. William J. Bryan vs. **Rep. William H. Taft**)
- 1904 (Dem. Alton Parker vs. **Rep. Theodore Roosevelt**)
- 1900 (Dem. William J. Bryan vs. **Rep. William McKinley**)
- 1896 (Dem. William J. Bryan vs. **Rep. William McKinley**)
- 1892 (**Dem. Grover Cleveland** vs. Rep. Benjamin Harrison and Populist James Weaver)
- 1888 (Dem. Grover Cleveland vs. **Rep. Benjamin Harrison**)
- 1884 (**Dem. G. Cleveland** vs. Rep. James Blaine)
- 1880 (Dem. Winfield Hancock vs. **Rep. James Garfield**)
- 1876 (Dem. Samuel Tilden vs. **Rep. Rutherford B. Hayes**)
- 1856 (**Dem. James Buchanan** vs. Rep. John Frémont and Know Nothing Millard Fillmore)
- 1852 (**Dem. Franklin Pierce** vs. Whig Winfield Scott)
- 1848 (Dem. Lewis Cass vs. **Whig Zachary Taylor** and Free Soil Martin Van Buren)